# How do I disable SSL for a Great Expectations connection configuration?

Tags: python, great-expectations

I'd like to use [Great Expectations](http://greatexpectations.io) to validate some of our data and data pipelines via [Trino](https://trino.io).

I'm reasonably sure I have the right configuration, which I'll paste in below. It doesn't work because (I think) it's trying to connect via SSL. For the particular environment I'm trying to use, we don't have SSL configured. (It's a testbed inside of a VPC, so there's no risk and the extra complication seemed unnecessary.)

Is there a way to pass a configuration option into the datasource configuration to disable SSL? I spent a long time searching through the documentation and couldn't find anything.

Configuration object in Python:

```
datasource_config = {
    "name": "my_trino_datasource",
    "class_name": "Datasource",
    "execution_engine": {
        "class_name": "SqlAlchemyExecutionEngine",
        "connection_string": "trino://username:password@URI:8080/hive/default",
    },
    "data_connectors": {
        "default_runtime_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "RuntimeDataConnector",
            "batch_identifiers": ["default_identifier_name"],
        },
        "default_inferred_data_connector_name": {
            "class_name": "InferredAssetSqlDataConnector",
            "include_schema_name": True,
        },
    },
}
```

And the error:

```
DatasourceInitializationError: Cannot initialize datasource my_trino_datasource, error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='URI', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/statement (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```